# What is the recommended OS for compiling a Windows binary for Litecoin?

Tags: litecoin, compiling, litecoin-qt

I'd like to compile Litecoin for Windows, but have difficulties doing so. To be specific: I want to create the Windows executable (.exe) GUI (qt) Litecoin client (to be more specific I want to compile the executable for an alt-coin based on litecoin, but the code base is the same as litecoin).

Many tutorials are either focused on compiling for Linux, or they focus on Bitcoin compiling, which is a bit different nowadays than Litecoin. Rather than explaining my specific problems, which are likely unique to my situation, I was wondering what a recommended Operating System (and version) is to compile Litecoin? Who has specific (preferably smooth) experience building the GUI litecoin client for Windows?

A useful relevant topic is this one:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=149479.0

But this is based on bitcoin, not litecoin. [This](http://andarazoroflove.org/how-to-create-alt-coin-scrypt-clones-for-fun-and-profit-bitcoin-litecoin-secrets-exposed/) referenced tutorial has a bit on Windows, but it's not too optimistic:

> Windows -Qt
>
> This is the trickiest one to crack of the GUI wallets. I am going to
>   detail how I got this to work and offer you an easy way to get the
>   dependencies in an attempt to make this work for you too. That said,
>   it may not–and I’ve already said I won’t do tech support. So here’s
>   the deal. I got this to work and then duplicated it on a second
>   machine to ensure it wasn’t a fluke! Most of the information needed to
>   compile the basic coind.exe or GUI wallet is in this thread:
>   https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=149479.0 Unfortunately nothing
>   is as easy as it seems, and although the MinGW and QT installs went
>   fine, I couldn’t compile it without a few tweaks to the .pro file.

In this tutorial, Windows is used to create the executable, but I understand one can also use Linux to create Windows executables, right? There are few experiences documenting successful or smooth compiling of Litecoin (forks) for Windows, so I was wondering if people do have good experiences doing so and what kind of OS or approach they used.

Comment: I'd go with Ubuntu as it's the distribution all guides are most likely going to focus on.

Comment: On windows this guide helped me: http://andarazoroflove.org/how-to-create-alt-coin-scrypt-clones-for-fun-and-profit-bitcoin-litecoin-secrets-exposed/

Comment: The title of your question is misleading. The best OS for compiling any bitcoin variant would clearly be a Linux dist. What you're asking is "What is the recommended OS for compiling a Windows binary for Litecoin."

Comment: I've tried using the following as a baseline,

https://bitcoinqtmsvc2012.codeplex.com/

however also needed some tweaking, but usefull resource for anyone looking to try.

Answer (score 1):

The Litecoin source tree, in the doc/ folder, provides a [file regarding building on Windows](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/v0.8.6.3-mark2/doc/build-msw.md), using [MinGW and MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/). I can't personally vouch for those instructions, never having used them myself, so if you go that route, good luck. The way that the release binaries are built, if I'm not mistaken, is using the [Gitian builder](http://www.gitian.org/). If you're looking to do a Windows build, I would try that. If you want to actually use Gitian, you can clone the repo, and use the readme file to get Gitian set up, and then follow [the build segment of the release process](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/blob/v0.8.6.3-mark2/doc/release-process.md#perform-gitian-builds) to do the actual build. On the other hand, if you're not necessarily looking for determinism or the ability to reproduce the exact build, you could try taking a look at the [Gitian build scripts](https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin/tree/v0.8.6.3-mark2/contrib/gitian-descriptors) to see what packages are being used, what commands are run, et cetera, and try to reproduce that on a Linux system.

Answer (score -1):

I have compiled litecoin-qt on Ubuntu 12.04 before. First install the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev build-essential libboost1.48-all-dev libssl-dev libdb++-dev libminiupnpc-dev
```

Then, in the directory of the litecoin source code, run

```
qmake
make
```

And you're done!

However, the compiled file is a Linux binary, so you'll have to use it on Linux. As far as I know, trying to compile a Windows binary on Linux would be even harder than just compiling it on Windows.

**Note**: This answer was posted before the question was clarified.

Comment: Thanks but not really what I am looking for. I am specifically looking for compiling the Windows executable...

Comment: The question should be rephrased, as it's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking which is the best version of Windows to run while compiling litecoin?

Comment: @user1162541: I think it would be best if you explained your "unique situation" and why you can't just use the provided binary.

Comment: @John Thanks, I have rephrased the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Tony I foresee the need to frequently recompile and would like to find the best configuration for this, so before trying to solve this problem I'd like to see if there are specific OS configurations that people recommend that make the process overall easier. I have added more detail in the post.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you making your own altcoin? If not, I don't see why you can't just download the Windows binary provided by the altcoin devs.

Comment: @Tony Yes I am making my own litecoin-based altcoin (see edited post). This is why compiling is necessary.